# multiple condition in one case when then create a new column as an aggregate of other column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've this query that works fine :

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
      CASE WHEN SUM(B.col3) > 0 THEN 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT B.col4) > 1 THEN 
         SUM(B.col5*1) / (SUM(B.col6*1) / (SUM(B.col7)/ COUNT(distinct B.col4))) 
         ELSE SUM(B.col5*1) / (SUM(B.col6*1) / SUM(B.col7)) 
        END 
        END AS NewCol

FROM table A
INNER JOIN table_ B on A.col1 = B.col1_ AND  A.col2 = B.col2_
WHERE B.DATE = '2022-01-31' AND filter = 1
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

But i would like to move the date condition in the case when instead in the where clause because in my full query i compute other agregate not based on this date

to make it easier i would like to use CASE WHEN in SQL like this

```
CASE WHEN DATE = '2022-01-31' AND SUM(col3) > 0 AND COUNT(DISTINCT col4) > 1 
THEN  SUM(col3)/COUNT(DISTINCT col4)
ELSE SUM(col3) END 
AS NewCol
```

but it doesn't work and return this message :

Edit : Error's message is SQL compilation error: Aggregate functions cannot be nested: [COUNT(DISTINCT col3)] nested in [SUM(IFF((DATE = (CAST('2022-01-31' AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)))) AND (col2 > (CAST(0 AS FLOAT))) AND ((COUNT(DISTINCT col3)) > 1), 1, 0))]

And when i'm writing :

```
CASE WHEN (DATE = '2022-01-31' AND SUM(col3) > 0 AND COUNT(distinct col4) > 1) 
THEN  SUM(col3)/COUNT(distinct col4))
ELSE SUM(col3) END 
AS NewCol
```

I've this following error's message :

SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 18 'DATE' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.

how to code this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: "doesn't work" is not that helpful. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: There is an extra `)` after `SUM(col2)/COUNT(distinct col3)` which you should remove.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: i use snowsql :)

Comment: That isn't the full query. And since you're getting an error about nesting of aggregates it seems likely that the parts you've left out are important. The error text seems to imply that you're trying to sum that entire expression?

Comment: A group of rows would generally have many different dates. You can't test for a single date value that way. Using `min(Date)` would eliminate that error that doesn't necessarily do the right thing though.

Answer (score 0):

When the DATE filter is in the WHERE clause, you only get rows that met that critia

Thus to move that out of the WHERE you need to filter all the SUM's the same.

the first point is your inner CASE statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT B.col4) > 1 THEN 
        SUM(B.col5*1) / (SUM(B.col6*1) / (SUM(B.col7) / COUNT(distinct B.col4))) 
    ELSE SUM(B.col5*1) / (SUM(B.col6*1) / SUM(B.col7)) 
END
```

can be replaced with

```
IFF(SUM(B.col3) > 0, SUM(B.col5*1)/(SUM(B.col6*1) / (SUM(B.col7*1) / greatest(COUNT(DISTINCT B.col4), 1))), null) AS NewCol_3
```

but these all need to be guarded via a date filter.

So we create so data that has two sets of results, and one of those results will be filtered out when the filter is present, and the other will not, so we can check the math all works:

```
with table_a(col1, col2, filter) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (1,10, 1),
        (2,11, 1)
), table_b(col1_, col2_, date, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) as (
   SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (1, 10, '2022-01-31', 1, 99001, 100, 6, 3),
        (1, 10, '2022-01-31', 1, 99002, 100, 6, 3),
        (1, 10, '2022-01-30', 1, 99001, 100, 6, 3),
        (2, 11, '2022-01-31', 1, 99001, 100, 6, 3),
        (2, 11, '2022-01-31', 1, 99002, 100, 6, 3)
)
```

first lets show that the two forms of calculations are the same:

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    col2,
    
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(B.col3) > 0 THEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT B.col4) > 1 THEN 
                    SUM(B.col5*1) / (SUM(B.col6*1) / (SUM(B.col7) / COUNT(distinct B.col4))) 
                ELSE SUM(B.col5*1) / (SUM(B.col6*1) / SUM(B.col7)) 
        END 
    END AS NewCol
    -- ABOVE ALL ORIGNAL CODE
    
    ,SUM(B.col3) as s_col3
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT B.col4) as c_col4
    ,SUM(B.col5*1) as math_5
    ,SUM(B.col6*1) as math_6
    ,SUM(B.col7*1) as math_7
    ,IFF(s_col3 > 0, math_5/(math_6 / (math_7 / greatest(c_col4, 1))), null) AS NewCol_2
    -- ABOVE origin decomposed into part and rewritten
    
FROM table_a AS A
JOIN table_b AS B 
    ON A.col1 = B.col1_ AND  A.col2 = B.col2_
WHERE filter = 1 
  AND B.DATE = '2022-01-31'
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

| COL1 | COL2 | NEWCOL | S_COL3 | C_COL4 | MATH_5 | MATH_6 | MATH_7 | NEWCOL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 50 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 12 | 6 | 50 |
| 2 | 11 | 50 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 12 | 6 | 50 |

and with the date filter commented out, we see the `(1,10)` row is summing to much data:

| COL1 | COL2 | NEWCOL | S_COL3 | C_COL4 | MATH_5 | MATH_6 | MATH_7 | NEWCOL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 75 | 3 | 2 | 300 | 18 | 9 | 75 |
| 2 | 11 | 50 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 12 | 6 | 50 |

Now if we put a `iff(B.DATE = '` inside each sum to restrict the sum to that wanted inputs.

```
    ,SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col3,null)) as fs_col3
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col4,null)) as fc_col4
    ,SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col5*1,null)) as fmath_5
    ,SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col6*1,null)) as fmath_6
    ,SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col7*1,null)) as fmath_7
    ,IFF(fs_col3 > 0, fmath_5/(fmath_6 / (fmath_7 / greatest(fc_col4, 1))), null) AS NewCol_3
```

for the DATE filter being present we get:

| COL1 | COL2 | NEWCOL | FS_COL3 | FC_COL4 | FMATH_5 | FMATH_6 | FMATH_7 | NEWCOL_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 50 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 12 | 6 | 50 |
| 2 | 11 | 50 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 12 | 6 | 50 |

and with the filter removed we get `newcol` being wrong, but `newcol_3` as correct.

| COL1 | COL2 | NEWCOL | FS_COL3 | FC_COL4 | FMATH_5 | FMATH_6 | FMATH_7 | NEWCOL_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 75 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 12 | 6 | 50 |
| 2 | 11 | 50 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 12 | 6 | 50 |

So lastly I will show the wanted answer in three different forms, ALL-In-One CASE, ALL-In-One IFF, and in discrete steps, personally I am a big fan of the last one.

```
with table_a(col1, col2, filter) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (1,10, 1),
        (2,11, 1)
), table_b(col1_, col2_, date, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) as (
   SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (1, 10, '2022-01-31', 1, 99001, 100, 6, 3),
        (1, 10, '2022-01-31', 1, 99002, 100, 6, 3),
        (1, 10, '2022-01-30', 1, 99001, 100, 6, 3),
        (2, 11, '2022-01-31', 1, 99001, 100, 6, 3),
        (2, 11, '2022-01-31', 1, 99002, 100, 6, 3)
)
SELECT 
    col1,
    col2,
    NewCol_1,
    NewCol_2,
    NewCol_3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        col1,
        col2,

        -- ALL-IN-ONE DONE IN CASE FORM
        CASE 
            WHEN SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col3,null)) > 0 THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col4,null)) > 1 THEN 
                        SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col5*1,null)) / (SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col6*1,null)) / (SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col7*1,null)) / COUNT(DISTINCT iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col4,null)))) 
                    ELSE SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col5*1,null)) / (SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col6*1,null)) / SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col7*1,null))) 
            END 
        END AS NewCol_1

        --  ALL-IN-ONE DONE IN IFF FORM
        ,IFF(SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col3,null)) > 0, SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col5*1,null))/(SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col6*1,null)) / (SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col7*1,null)) / greatest(COUNT(DISTINCT iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col4,null)), 1))), null) AS NewCol_2

        -- Done as parts

        ,SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col3,null)) as fs_col3
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col4,null)) as fc_col4
        ,SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col5*1,null)) as fmath_5
        ,SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col6*1,null)) as fmath_6
        ,SUM(iff(B.DATE = '2022-01-31',B.col7*1,null)) as fmath_7
        ,IFF(fs_col3 > 0, fmath_5/(fmath_6 / (fmath_7 / greatest(fc_col4, 1))), null) AS NewCol_3

    FROM table_a AS A
    JOIN table_b AS B 
        ON A.col1 = B.col1_ AND  A.col2 = B.col2_
    WHERE filter = 1 
      --AND B.DATE = '2022-01-31'
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
```

gives:

| COL1 | COL2 | NEWCOL_1 | NEWCOL_2 | NEWCOL_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 11 | 50 | 50 | 50 |

Comment: It’s very clear, Thanks for taking the time to support your answer !